# How to define UI inputs in a separate file in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to define an app based on a **tabsetPanel**. Each **tabPanel** within it should have it's own **sidebarPanel** to define it's own set of inputs.

There are 7 **tabPanel**s, each with various types of inputs. In order to avoid having a messy code I would like to have a separate .R file just to define the inputs.

Any advice on how to accomplish this ?

(I have tried to do exactly this by defining typical R functions to declare the **sidebarPanel**s. I create a master.R file that sources a ui.R file, a server.R file and a ui_inputs.R file. The problem is that unless I run ui_inputs.R manually in the console the app will not run. Maybe there is some shiny-specific way to use this functional approach that I am not aware of ?).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A min reprex might help us understand better but have you tried modules - https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it should work if you use the `source` command like this in your UI file (ui.R) :

```
source(file.path("your_directory", "ui_inputs.R"), local = true)$value
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that if I source the ui_inputs.R inside ui.R file it works, but if I source it in the master.R it does not work.